# Django - How do form template tags work?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

This is a simple question, but I can't find the answer. The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#the-template) show the following example for calling a form in template just using `{{ form }}`:

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This doesn't fully explain how the `{{ form }}` tag in the template works if I'm not missing something.

I have my some snippets of my code here which show the problem I'm having with my form tag which currently returns blank:

forms.py

```
class addtaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    task_name = forms.CharField(label='task_name')
    priority = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES)
```

views.py

```
def add_task(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        return HttpResponse("works!")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^add_task/$', 'todo.views.add_task', name='add_task')
```

tasks.html

```
<form id="add_task" action="/add_task/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ add_task_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The `{{add_task_form}}` is just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{{ form }}` is not a template tag, it is a context variable. By default `Form` instances are rendered using the [`Form.as_table()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options) method.  So you have to pass such variable to the template in the [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/#the-view) call:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def add_task(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addtaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something useful and redirect
    else:
        form = addtaskForm()
    return render(request, 'tasks.html', {'add_task_form': form})
```

I suggest you to carefully read the full explanation of the forms in the [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/) chapter of the django documentation.